# How to let a Node script fail in a GitLab Pipeline?

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci, npx

We have a GitLab Pipeline in which we let run npm/npx commands/scripts but the issue is that the script doesn't expose an exit code 1 when it produces errors.

Here is the the pipeline:

```
stages:
  - validate

image: node:latest

verify:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - 'npm i'
    - 'npx orval --config ./orval.config.js'
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - src/
```

Despite the fact that the last script `npx orval --config ./orval.config.js` produces an *SyntaxError* (see below) the pipeline is in the end successfull (exit code is 0) but from our perspective it should not (exit code is 1) because of the *SyntaxError*.

```
 Start orval v6.15.0 - A swagger client generator for typescript
dispo-file: Cleaning output folder
⚠️  SyntaxError: Swagger schema validation failed.
  #/paths/~1disposition/get/parameters/0/schema/type must be equal to one of the allowed values
  #/paths/~1disposition/get/parameters/0/schema must have required property '$ref'
  #/paths/~1disposition/get/parameters/0/schema must match exactly one schema in oneOf
  #/paths/~1disposition/get/parameters/0 must have required property '$ref'
  #/paths/~1disposition/get/parameters/0 must match exactly one schema in oneOf

 dispo-file - Your OpenAPI spec has been converted into ready to use orval!
```

FYI: [Orval](https://orval.dev/overview) generates TypeScript classes for an OpenAPI spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to self-description, `orval(1)` does not have proper exit status codes in all conditions.

The procedure with it is to create an issue, describe the situation and ask if they would accept a pull request.

They then normally confirm they do and then you file the pull request.

### Alternative to a Pull-Request

Alternatively you could make it a pipeline:

```yaml
verify:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - 'npm i'
    - 'npx orval --config ./orval.config.js | grep -vqz "Swagger schema validation failed"'
```

cf. `grep(1)`.

#### Pipeline Variant with the Stream Editor

Pipeline variant passing the whole output and exiting early (or late with additional `-z`) and non-zero in case of the error:

```yaml
verify:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - 'npm i'
    - 'npx orval --config ./orval.config.js | sed "/Swagger schema validation failed/q1"
```

cf. `sed(1)`, `q1` is a GNU extension (for the `1` as exit-code, which is required to make the script fail on error).

---

Thanks to [`kladderradatsch`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5841551/kladderradatsch) for reminding [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76289721/how-to-let-a-node-script-fail-in-a-gitlab-pipeline/76291639?noredirect=1#comment134541139_76291639) that `grep -v ...` was wrong and `grep -vqz ...` the working variant (at least `-q` was missing for non-zero exit status).

Comment: Thank you, this approach works. But the grep must be in this way: `... | grep -vqz ...` in order to stream the entire output (-z) and -q makes the output quiet.

Comment: @kladderradatsch: yes, correct, I was quick with that one, but you got the idea, that''s great. At time of writing I wanted to preserve the output so that it is not hidden and had a pipe like `sed '/Swagger schema validation failed/q1'` in mind but wanted to give one with `grep`.  Albeit `grep -v ...` is to be corrected in the answer and I understand you prefer to have it quiet I'm a bit surprised about -z not for what it does but that you consider it required. Perhaps to not stop orval early?

Comment: Actually, Orval's output is important to check afterwards within the Pipeline so removing `-q` makes sense. The crucial part here is the `-z` option to remove each newline so `grep` works correctly.

Comment: In the man page of `grep` one can read as to option `-q`: `Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found, even if an error was detected.` So I think what you have written above is wrong.

Comment: @kladderradatsch: `-v` reverses that, giving non-zero exit code if found. That part I've tested. The difference with `-z` is that is processes the whole output while without `-z` it will exit the moment the error is reported, which will stop the pipeline and mark the build step as failure close to immediatly, no files will be generated even (that may or may not be wanted, no judgement from my end, just description).

Comment: If you want to keep the output (which is what I'd also had in mind originally) use the `sed` command in the pipeline. I can add it to the question if you like. IIRC it requires GNU SED to have the exit code which is important to make the build fail.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense to me. Do it. Thank you!

Comment: @kladderradatsch: Done editing the answer, let me know if this is clear and what you're looking for.

Comment: And btw, this is a related (open) issue in Orval: [ResolverError not process exit code #797](https://github.com/anymaniax/orval/issues/797) - I think it is interesting as it means that there could be some more places that can fail without noticing in CI. So treat the `orval` invocations with care in your CI. It is maybe worth to have some smoke tests afterwards as a workaround, but actually this must be handled in `orval` itself so that it makes sense using it in CI.